# How to count differences between current date and some past dates in sqlite? Local Machine's date can be changed

Tags: sqlite

Okay. This question seems so common and solved. 
I can find differences between current date and some past-date in sqlite. I use julianDay('now') to retrieve current date but problem is local machine's date can be changed. I need the amount of days since the profile has been created. So if I use `cast(julianDay('now') - julianDay(creation_date) as int)`, it will work fine until someone changes the local machine date.

So, how can I find the differences? Is there any event_scheduler in sqlite? I've googled it but found no suitable answer.

TIA

Comment: You calculation is correct in an SQLite database.  If you don't trust the local computer time then you will have to reference an internet timesource.  If that is the case it is not an SQLite problem.

Comment: I can't use any remote server. No internet connection is allowed. That's the main problem. what about triggers? is it possible to count days after every 24 hrs?